# EventBus calling two different handlers for a single post

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I am having problems with EventBus 3.0.0 where I post a single event like this:

```
Call<List<SessionSpec>> call = httpService.getSessionSpecs();
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<SessionSpec>>() {

   @Override
   public void onResponse(Call<List<SessionSpec>> call, Response<List<SessionSpec>> response)  {
       if (response.isSuccessful())  {
           List<SessionSpec> specs = response.body();
           EventBus.getDefault().post((List<SessionSpec>)specs);
       }
       else Log.e(TAG, "sendSessionSpecs(): request NOT successful");
   }

   @Override
   public void onFailure(Call<List<SessionSpec>> call, Throwable t)  {
      Log.e(TAG, "sendSessionsSpecs(): failed");
   }
});
```

I have two subscribers in the same fragment, each with different signatures, but they are both getting called from a single post:

```
@Subscribe
public void onSessionSpec(List<SessionSpec> specs) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onSessionSpec(): entered");
    Log.d(TAG, "    : number of session specs: " + specs.size());
}
```

The second subscriber is defined as:

```
@Subscribe
public void onOverlayType(List<OverlayType> types) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onOverlayType(): entered");
    Log.d(TAG, "    : number of overlay types: " + types.size());
}
```

Both of these callbacks are in a single fragment which is active when the post is done and I have verified that the post is only called once. When the single SessionSpec event is posted, both the onSessionSpec and the onOverlayType callbacks are dispatched by EventBus with the event type of List> so the onOverlayType callback receives the wrong type  in its callback argument. The class OverlayType is a simple POJO class with 2 members, a int "sid" and a String "name". The class SessionSpec is more complex; it does have a member String "name" but other than that, nothing else is common between these 2 classes. I have verified that there is nothing closely resembling "OverlayType" in the SessionSpec class.

The interface definition is this:

```
public interface VcapHttpInterface {

    @GET("overlay/types")
    Call<List<OverlayType>> getOverlayTypes();

    @GET("session/list")
    Call<List<SessionSpec>> getSessionSpecs();

    @GET("session/{id}")
    Call<Session> getSession(@Path("id") int sid);
```

}

The getSession event post/callback has no problems.

I have spend all day trying to figure what is going wrong so I am clueless at this point. Anybody know what might be wrong with my code?

Thanks,
-Andres

Edit:  How does EventBus know which handler to call for a particular response?  Some posts I have read said that EventBus does not use the handler signature, but how else would it know how to map a response to the right subscribed handler routine?  Is there a way to explicitly define the handler callback for a given event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EventBus` checks the class of the object that you are posting, and calls the methods that expect that class in their parameters. In your case you are posting an object which is a `List`. In both your listeners you expect an object of type `List`. It doesn't matter what generic you put in `OverlayType` or `SessionSpec`, eventbus will call both. In order to make it work you gotta define to models as events.

```
public class OverlayTypeEvent {

    public List<OverlayType> types;

    public OverlayTypeEvent(List<OverlayType> types) {
        this.types = types;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SessionSpecEvent {

    public List<SessionSpec> types;

    public SessionSpecEvent(List<SessionSpec> types) {
        this.types = types;
    }
}
```

And listen on them seperatley. Then post events with the specific type.

```
@Subscribe
public void onSessionSpec(OverlayTypeEvent event) {
    List<OverlayType> overlayTypes = event.overlayType;
}
```

Comment: that did it. It all makes sense now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create new class as a container everytime you send a list data, you can you [Pair](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair) as simple container, it has two generic fields (**first** and **second**) to contain variables.

You can use **first** as a key to check the type of class, **second** contains the actually data.

```
List<SessionSpec> specs = response.body();
EventBus.getDefault().post(new Pair<>(SessionSpec.class.getSimpleName(), specs));
```

Receive data:

```
@Subscribe
public void onSessionSpec(Pair<String, List<SessionSpec>> specContainer){
    if (SessionSpec.class.getSimpleName().equals(specContainer.first)) {
        List<SessionSpec> sessionSpecs = specContainer.second;
    }
}

@Subscribe
public void onOverlayType(Pair<String, List<OverlayType>> overlayContainer) {
    if (OverlayType.class.getSimpleName().equals(overlayContainer.first)) {
        List<OverlayType> overlayTypes = overlayContainer.second;
    }
}
```

*Advantage* of this solution: Reduce creating unneeded classes.
*Disadvantage*: both ***onSessionSpec*** and ***onOverlayType*** get called.